# Private overriden virtual functions in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, private-members, access-specifier

Is there any point to making virtual member functions, overridden from a base class private, if those are public in the base class?

```
struct base {
    virtual void a();
};

struct derived : base {
// ...
private:
    void a() override;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forced to do a 2-phase construction on the implementation class (i.e. have an `init()` method as well as or instead of a constructor that has to be called (I know, but there are reasons), then this stops you calling any /other/ methods directly on the instance pointer before you pass it back as an interface pointer. Go the extra mile, make the inheritance private, and have your one public init function return the interface pointer!

Another reason is you just don't /need/ to write `public:` in a final implementation class declaration, so then by default everything is private. But why you would do that and use struct instead of class I don't know. Perhaps this was converted from class at some point due to a style war?

Comment: there is no difference between `class` and `struct` other than the default access

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Indeed. So if you have an implementation class, it can all be default `private`, because none of the methods will be called directly. What then happens is some style warrior comes along and says "This should be a struct because 'the blah is a wotsit'", a  rule that means nothing outside that circle, and junior programmer changes it to struct (because style warriors only change stuff themselves when it will /really/ piss off the original author) and puts `private:` in, so that it behaves the same, because nobody wants to retest it. And then you have the OP code.

Comment: I would rather write a factory that always returns a fully initialized object than doing this. You can use a tag class to allow only the factory to create an object if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your design, I see one cannot call `derived::a` directly, but only through a `base` interface.

Is there any point? Consider that, once we have a `derived` instance, we can always up-cast to its base, so given

```
derived d;
```

while `d.a()` wouldn't compile, we can always do

```
base & b = d;
b.a(); //which actually calls derived::a
```

In other words: `derived::a` is not *that* private, after all, and I would discourage this design, which can be confusing to the user.

Things change if the members private in `derived` are private in `base`, as well: this time it is clear that they just cannot be called directly, outside `base` or `derived`.

Let's say we have a couple of functions, and want them to be called conditionally, according to a value passed as an argument to a third one:

```
struct base 
{
    void dosomething(bool x)
    {
        if(x)
        {
            do_this();
        }
        else
        {
            do_that();
        }
    }
private:
    virtual void do_this(){}
    virtual void do_that(){}
};
```

Thus a derived class could be like:

```
struct derived : base 
{
private:
    void do_this() override { }
    void do_that() override { }
};
```

and no other class can call them, unless it extended `base` itself:

```
derived d;
d.dosomething(true); //will call do_this() in derived
d.dosomething(false); //will call do_that() in derived

d.do_that() //won't compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you inherit the base class as private. Otherwise, it is more of a weird explicit-like restriction - user has to has to make an explicit conversion to use the function - it is generally ill advised as few will be able to comprehend the author's intention.

If you want to restrict some functions from base class, make a private/protected inheritance and via `using` keyword declare which base-methods you want to be protected/public in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

The same reasoning as for non-virtual methods applies: If only the class itself is supposed to call it make it private.

Consider the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
struct base {
    void foo() { a() ; b(); }
    virtual void a() = 0;
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

struct derived : base {
private:
    void a() override {}
    void b() override {}
};
int main()
{
   derived().foo();
}
```

Perhaps `a` and `b` should have been `protected`, but anyhow the `derived` can change accesibility and it requires some documentation so that `derived` knows how it is supposed to implement `a` and `b`.

Comment: Why not declare the template methods private in the base class? That would express the intention that these are methods that are used internally by the class.

Comment: @Jens I took that as a premise. I have to admit that my example isnt too convincing